# First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'unicode'

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to django and I'm following some tutorial to learn it. From this tutorial I'm trying to build a blog but I'm stuck at this following error.

```
First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'unicode'.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/2018/10/16/todays_post/
Django Version: 1.11.16
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'unicode'.
Exception Location: C:\Users\...\mysite\python-ve\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py in get_object_or_404, line 90
Python Executable:  C:\Users\...\mysite\python-ve\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.15
```

Following is my model.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,self).get_queryset()\
        .filter(status='published')

class post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published','Published'),
    )

title = models.CharField(max_length=250) # field for the post title
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish') 
author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name ='blog_posts')
body = models.TextField()# text field. body of the post
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
status = models.CharField(max_length = 10, 
choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft') # to know the status of the post
objects = models.Manager()
published = PublishedManager()

class Meta: # sort results by the publish field in descending order
    ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):    
    return reverse('blog:post_detail', args[self.publish.year, 
    self.publish.strftime('%m'), self.publish.strftime('%d'), self.slug])
```

My views.py where the exception is:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import post

def post_list(request):
    posts = post.published.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html',{'posts':posts})

def post_detail(request, year, month,day,post):
    post = get_object_or_404(post, slug=post, status='published', 
    publish_year=year, publish_month=month, publish_day=day)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post':post})
```

I have looked for answers, some I was unable to understand so I have posted it here.

Comment: There is "clash" between the `post` parameter and the `post` class.

Answer (score 1):

Both your variable in the view, and the name of the class are `post`, so that means that in your view, we see:

```
def post_detail(request, year, month,day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(post, slug=post, status='published', 
    publish_year=year, publish_month=month, publish_day=day)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post':post})
```

`post` itself is thus a local variable (a parameter) that contains the `slug`, and it "hides" the outer variable `post` that refers to the model. I advise you to follow **PEP-8**, and thus rename your `post` class to `Post` (starting with an uppercase, and in camelcase). If you follow PEP-8 consistently, the clashes between local variables and class names, will normally not occur.

A fast (and not elegant) fix, is to import the model under a different name:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import post as post_model

def post_list(request):
    posts = post_model.published.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html',{'posts':posts})

def post_detail(request, year, month,day,post):
    post = get_object_or_404(post_model, slug=post, status='published', 
    publish_year=year, publish_month=month, publish_day=day)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post':post})
```

But I think it is definitely worth the effort to simply make your variables PEP-8 compliant.

Comment: @Sheshan: as said in the answer, it is however beneficial to rename the class, since otherwise it is likely you will keep encountering similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your `post` class to `Post`, and use it in `post_detail` view.

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post, status='published', publish_year=year, publish_month=month, publish_day=day)
```

In your code `get_object_or_404` function tries to use `post` argument from your view as model, but it is unicode.

Also it is a good practice to follow the UpperCaseCamelCase convention for class names.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the post in this code block

`def post_detail(request, year, month,day, slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(post, slug=slug, status='published',

              publish_year=year, publish_month=month, publish_day=day)
        return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post':post})`

And then extra tip, always start you model name with capital letters since they are classes, that's some good practice.